# Java HashSet and data type Short, incompatibility?

Tags: java, puzzle, hashset, short

Running this code:

```
    public class SomeSet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<Short> s = new HashSet<Short>();

        for (short i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            s.add(i);

            s.remove(i - 1);

        }

        System.out.println(s.size());

    }

}
```

Will print the value 100.

Why does it print this value?

Answer (score 10):

```
s.remove(i - 1);
```

The line above will attempt to remove `Integer` objects from the set, because all integer calculations in Java have `int` (or `long`) results. Since the set contains `Short` objects, the `remove()` method will not have any effect.

This (and similar problems) is the main reason why you should almost never use `short` (and, more so, `Short`). Using a `Set` implementation to contain autoboxed numbers incurs a massive (easily 1000%) overhead, so it's rather pointless to try and save space by using `Short` rather than `Integer`.

Comment: ... or `float` or `double` ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `remove(i-1)` calls the `remove` method with an `Integer` object, since `i-1` is of type `int` (which gets auto-boxed into an `Integer`).

To make sure that you call `remove` with a `Short` object use this:

```
s.remove((short) (i - 1));
```

Comment: Or more explicitly s.remove(Short.valueOf(i-1));

Comment: @Steve: which wouldn't compile as you'd need an explicit cast as well. Making it more explicit but also more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `i - 1` is `int`, so it gets autoboxed to an Integer.

Normally you'd expect a generic collection to prevent you performing operations which have arguments of the wrong type, but the interface to `Set<E>` is a bit loose.

Because the [remove](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) method of `Set<E>` takes an `Object` rather than an `E`, the compiler doesn't warn you that you're removing a different type to what the set contains.

To force it to be a `Short`, cast the numeric value to `(short)`. (casting to `(Short)` isn't allowed, and you'd have to cast the numeric value to use `Short.valueOf`)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the add method is generically typed `boolean add(E o)` so in your case of Set the add method will take a short, whereas the remove method is not generically typed `boolean remove(Object o)` so `i - 1` autoboxes to a Integer.  For any value of i `new Short(i).equals(new Integer(i))` will always be false.

Note that if you try `s.add(i - 1);` you will get a compiler error because `i - 1` becomes an instance of Integer and the types Integer and Short do not match.